# zend Validate customized message on callback

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I have following calss to validate my input elements.

```
class Validator_FormValidator {
    public function genValid($value){

        $chainValid = new Zend_Validate();

        $strLenV = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 4, 'max' => 10));
        $strLenV->setMessage("You have entered a Invalid value","stringLengthInvalid");
        $chainValid->addValidator($strLenV);

        return $result;
    }

}
```

and then in the index controller

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->form = new Form_LoginForm();
        $this->view->registrationForm = new Form_RegistrationForm();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())   {
          $validatorObj = new Validator_FormValidator();
          $valid = new Zend_Validate_Callback(array($validatorObj,'genValid'));
          $username = $this->_getParam('username');           

          if ($valid->isValid($username)) { echo 'success'; }
          else {
               echo 'failure';
               foreach ($valid->getMessages() as $message) {
                  echo "$message\n";
              }

          }
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to add customized error messages in my Validator_FormValidator class which are not display in my controller failure condition. 
Could any of you plz guide how to do this? Is this what I am trying to do(createing a separate validator class and put all validation function in it) is a good practice?

Comment: I think you can use zendx jquery for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual way of creating your own, [custom validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html)s is by extending `Zend_Validate_Abstract` or any class of already existing validator, e.g. `Zend_Validate_StringLength`. This way you could customize validation process as well as its all properties, e.g. messages.